# Skeletal groupoids and strict coherences

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

I am reading [Morton's paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10485-010-9225-0) on 2-Vector spaces and groupoids.

On page numbered 655, he has the following diagram of groupoids and functors:

[image: Diagram of Groupoids]

His words:
"In principle we need only require this diagram commute weakly: that is, there is an isomorphism $s_1 s\to s_2t$. For the most part, since the construction we mean to give is invariant under equivalence of groupoids, and taking $A_1$ to be skeletal makes this strict, we will assume strict commutativity, though we shall indicate where the argument must be changed to accommodate the weak case."

**Question**:  I don't understand how taking $A_1$ to be skeletal makes the diagram strict. It is my understanding that the skeletal groupoid will be a bunch of discrete points with automorphisms. Now since $A_1$ still has automorphisms, natural isomorphisms need not be identity, right? So how can we say that the square (on the left, say) commutes on the nose?

Comment: Your objection is valid. Taking skeletal groupoids only solves the problem of making the diagram commute on the level of object sets.